# JavaScript function won't run twice with different inputs

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to make this function run twice with two different inputs, but it only runs once.

the code:

```js
const data1dolphins = 44 + 23 + 71;
const data1Koalas = 65 + 54 + 49;
const data2dolphins = 85 + 54 + 41;
const data2Koalas = 23 + 34 + 27;

function calcAverage(data, dataValue) {
  const scoreAverage = data * dataValue
  return scoreAverage;
}

const data1DolphinsAverage = calcAverage(data1dolphins, 3)
const data1KoalasAverage = calcAverage(data1Koalas, 3)
const data2DolphinsAverage = calcAverage(data2dolphins, 3)
const data2KoalasAverage = calcAverage(data2Koalas, 3)

function checkWinner(avgTeamOne, avgTeamTwo) {
  if (avgTeamOne >= (avgTeamTwo * 2)) {
    console.log(`team one won with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}, while team two lost with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}`)
  } else if (avgTeamTwo >= (avgTeamOne * 2)) {
    console.log(`team two won with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}, while team one lost with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}`)
  }
  // console.log('testing round')
}

console.log('before')
checkWinner(data1DolphinsAverage, data1KoalasAverage)
console.log('middle')
checkWinner(data2DolphinsAverage, data2KoalasAverage)
console.log('after')
```

the output:

before

team one won with average score of : 540, while team two lost with average score of : 252

middle

after

Comment: May you add the data variables to the example?

Comment: perhaps neither `avgTeamOne >= (avgTeamTwo*2)` nor `avgTeamTwo >= (avgTeamOne*2)` is true

Comment: The checkWinner function has an if…else if block, but no else block. Guessing it’s not hitting either, so nothing is outputted. Trying adding an else statement with a console.log and see if you get output

Comment: Simply uncomment the console.log outside the if else block... I'm sure you will find the function is indeed running and your conditions aren't being met.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah thanks for the tip forgot to add it

Comment: @Bravo will try logging everything to check that just a minute

Comment: @MonicaGranbois yeah tried that and it worked just fine and the first function ran but still why did it skip the first two statments one of them should be valid right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried an else statement?

```
function checkWinner (avgTeamOne,avgTeamTwo){
    if(avgTeamOne >= (avgTeamTwo*2)) {
        console.log(`team one won with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}, while team two lost with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}`);
    } else if (avgTeamTwo >= (avgTeamOne*2)){
        console.log(`team two won with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}, while team one lost with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}`);
    } else { <<
        console.log("neither of these things happened."); <<
    } <<
}
```

I find it a bit hard to see your purpose, as you didn't provide values for `data1dolphins`, `data1Koalas`, `data2dolphins`, or `data2Koalas`, but I'm guessing that this is the fix that you need.

Comment: yes I did and it ran fine but when if  console.log(data1DolphinsAverage)=414 and
console.log(data1KoalasAverage)=504 and
console.log((2*data1KoalasAverage))=1008

Comment: yeah ok got it I see it now sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

the function ran fine after adding an else statment:

```
const data1dolphins = 44+23+71;
const data1Koalas = 65+54+49;
const data2dolphins = 85+54+41;
const data2Koalas = 23+34+27;

function calcAverage (data,dataValue){
  const scoreAverage =  data * dataValue
  return scoreAverage;
}

const data1DolphinsAverage = calcAverage(data1dolphins,3)
const data1KoalasAverage = calcAverage(data1Koalas,3)
const data2DolphinsAverage = calcAverage(data2dolphins,3)
const data2KoalasAverage = calcAverage(data2Koalas,3)

function checkWinner (avgTeamOne,avgTeamTwo){
  if(avgTeamOne >= (2*avgTeamTwo)) {
    console.log(`team one won with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}, while team two lost with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}`)
  } else if (avgTeamTwo >= (2*avgTeamOne)){
    console.log(`team two won with average score of : ${avgTeamTwo}, while team one lost with average score of : ${avgTeamOne}`)
  }else {
    console.log('none of the above')
  }
}

console.log('before')
checkWinner(data1DolphinsAverage, data1KoalasAverage)
console.log('middle')
checkWinner(data2DolphinsAverage, data2KoalasAverage)
console.log('after')
```